# onunload event in chrome or is there any alternative work arounds

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

as i searched quite for this issue, including google chrome support sites, [Chrome Bug Issues](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=31853), as they are not yet fixed the problem. Right now i have a situation where i should use onuload or onbeforeunload event in my JS Snippets, as its working nicely in other browsers. these are the things which i've tried of now

- using Page Hide or PageShow as Webkit provides alternative to this problem, but the result is same, chrome is not firing the onpagehide event only. after bit of exploration i come to know pagehide and pageshow methods are applicapble to firefox only.
- Secondly i tried setting Async=false, as suggested in this answer [OnUnload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8330979/jquery-unload-with-an-ajax-call-not-working-in-chrome) .
- I'm using Chrome Dev.Version (17.0.963.12 dev-m).

Is there any work around for this weird problem, i hope anyone already experienced the same problem, and they may got some alternative.

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" >
function DoSomethingonUnload()
{
alert ('im unloading');

}
</script>
<body onunload="DoSomethingonUnload();"> //need alternative which can work in (ie,chrome,ff)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use jquery:)
http://api.jquery.com/unload/

Comment: can u come up with some examples, so that we can understood.

Comment: it works :) :)  i wish i could hav upvote your ans. u just commented. so i'm upvoting your comment :)

Comment: jQuery's unload() method was deprecated in version 1.8.  Also, my experiments with Android 4.x and iOS 6.x, showed that unload() was not called (or at least couldn't write a cookie when it was called).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery, I achieved this task. Using Bind function with onbeforeunload event [jQuery bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) . it works seamlessly :) :) thank you @ Sergey Ratnikov