# JQuery bind unload event in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I searched [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634530/onunload-event-in-chrome-or-is-there-any-alternative-work-arounds) for a solution for the unload event in Google Chrome.

The following code is calling myFunction in IE, FF but not in Chrome.

```
$(window).bind("unload",myFunction);
```

Is there an alternative (using JS or JQuery) to trigger the unload event in Chrome?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is jQuery unload not working in chrome and safari?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9973816/why-is-jquery-unload-not-working-in-chrome-and-safari)

Comment: myFunction is not using alert. Therefore, it shouldn't be blocked by Chrome, I've also tried other methods like $(window).on('beforeunload', function(e) {
   myFunction
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me in IE, FF and Chrome:

```
window.onbeforeunload = myFunction;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try beforeunload event:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(e) {
    //your function's body
});
```

Comment: It should work in Chrome as well, just callback function must return a string.